# RMarkdown Beamer make slide titles and add figures in loop

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer, presentation

I am new to RMarkdown and Beamer. I am trying to make a set of slides where each slide contains a JPG. I have a dozen to loop through. How do I set this up in a loop?

Here is the RMD file:

````
---
title: 'slideshow'
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "AnnArbor"
---

# Introduction

## Blah

- Text
- Here
- Etc.

# Images

## pic_1

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("../images/modelA_pic_1.jpg")
```

## pic_2

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("../images/modelA_pic_2.jpg")
```

## pic_3

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("../images/modelA_pic_3.jpg")
```

## pic_4

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("../images/modelA_pic_4.jpg")
```
````

I know I can put the slide titles and figure paths into a data frame, but I am not sure how to do this inside RMarkdown and how to loop through it to build the slide titles and insert the images.

```
title <- c('pic_1', 'pic_2', 'pic_3', 'pic_4')
fpath <- c('modelA_pic_1.jpg', 'modelA_pic_2.jpg', 'modelA_pic_3.jpg', 'modelA_pic_4.jpg')
fpath <- paste0("../images/", fpath)
myfiles <- data.frame(title, fpath)
```

**Updated Based on Accepted Answer**

Below is what I ended up using for my Rmd. [This page](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2010-02-09-how-to-do-image-animation-in-beamer.html) explains the basics of the `xmpmulti` package.

For this set up, my RMD is in one folder; the images are one folder up (`../`) and then in a folder called *temp* (`../temp/`). The images in this folder are named `test-1.png`, `test-2.png`, etc.

````
---
title: 'slideshow'
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "AnnArbor"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xmpmulti}
---

# Introduction

## Blah

- Text
- Here
- Etc.

```{=latex}
\end{frame}
\section{Images}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{picture 1}
\frametitle<2>{picture 2}
\centering
\multiinclude[format=png,start=1,end=2,graphics={width=1\textwidth}]{../temp/test}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
```

some test
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your images are named `pic-1.png` etc., then beamer has an automatic way to loop over the images via the `xmpmulti` package:

````
---
title: 'slideshow'
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "AnnArbor"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xmpmulti}
---

# Introduction

## Blah

- Text
- Here
- Etc.

```{=latex}
\end{frame}
\section{Images}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{picture 1}
\frametitle<2>{picture 2}
\frametitle<3>{picture 3}
\centering
\multiinclude[format=png,start=1,end=3,graphics={width=.6\textwidth}]{pic}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
```

some test
````

Comment: thanks for your answer, this looks like it should work but I am receiving an error. I updated the OP to reflect my attempt with your answer and the resulting error

Comment: @a11 The `_` key is for math - and math only. You must not use it in your frametitle without escaping, e.g. `../images/modelA\_pic\_1`

Comment: Quotes won't do anything to characters which are not allowed. With escaped underscores, this work fine for me: https://rstudio.cloud/project/2490816

Comment: I studied the xmpmulti package more and got it to work, thanks for your help